# Read secured pdf, Too low xss setting and cyclic dependencies

Tags: itext, pdfbox

I am stuck in owner password secured pdf reading. I have googled a lot tried different solutions but stuck in somewhere with details provided below :

Technology used : java 1.7 , struts 1.3
Task : read secured pdf.

Currently my tomcat/lib has around 190 jars relevant jars are :

1. iText-2.1.7
2. iTextPdf 5.5.13
3. pdfbox-app-1.8.6
4. bcprov-jdk16-141

Currently my code is like :

```
try{
    pdfReader reader= new pdfReader(src);
}catch(Exception e){
    //logs
}
```

I got error `org.bouncycastle.asn1.asn1primitive not found.`

So I added bcprov-ext-jdk14-1.47.

This resolved my issue on windows environment though while using it on Linux environment i got below error :

```
signer information does not match with signer information from other class in same package.
```

After further research I found that pdfbox has maven dependencies and accordingly used bcprov-jdk15on-1.49 and removed all old versions of bcprov.

Now my final issue is :

This combination : pdfbox-app-1.8.6 and bcpov-jdk15on-1.49 is causing below error

```
Too low xss setting and causing cyclic dependencies on two classes present in both jars.
```

Though this issue is reproducible on only few tomcats.

Please help.

Comment: Please read the dependencies page of PDFBox and use the latest versions, i.e. 1.8.15 or 2.0.11. The pages mention which bouncycastle version is needed. for 1.8, version 1.44 is needed: https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/dependencies.html But it's better to use 2.0.11 , this uses 1.54 https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/dependencies.html

Comment: You don't need 2 versions of iText, you can remove version 2.1.7.

Comment: Welcome to Bouncy Castle version hell. Unfortunately BC introduced major changes in minor version steps, and also unfortunately both iText and PDFBox depend on specific BC versions which of course differ and change from release to release. Thus, without a technology like OSGi you're always likely to stumble if multiple third party libraries of your project depend on BC.